# Dataframe value is sum between dates using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2. df1 is a uniform date range and default values of 0 in another column. So it looks like:

```
df1: 
     date          Val
0    2020-02-01     0
1    2020-02-02     0
2    2020-02-03     0
.
.
.
```

Meanwhile df2 simply records events occurring

```
df2: 
     date                   Val
0    2020-02-01-10:00:00     98
1    2020-02-01-13:54:09     55
2    2020-02-02-11:33:17     32         
.
.
.
```

I want the `df1.val[i]` to be the sum of all the values in df2 between the dates `df1.date[i] and df1.date[i+1]` .

I write the following lambda function but it does not work:

```
df1['val'] = df1.apply( lambda row: df2[ (df2.date < df1.date[row.index])].sum() )
```

help

Comment: I get an error saying Can Only compare identically labeled series objects

Comment: Hope you are looking for this df2 = df2.groupby([df2['date'].dt.date]).sum()

Comment: I don't think so. I want to populate the rows of df1 with the sum of values in a date range defined by row j and row j+1 of df1

Comment: What I understood was df2 has multiple records for same date and the sum of val is needed for each day that can be obtained by the above groupby operation usind date part, as the second step it can be joined with df1 to map the values for these dates

Comment: @kishoreVM you are right if the freq of df1 is 1 day but if the freq is 2 or 3 or more days, you can't use this method (I think)

Comment: @Corralien I agree with your point .. looking at the sample data provided in question I thought its 1 day

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a bare example. df1 may be minute-by-minute. In which case, I want the sum between two minute values

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut`:

```
>>> df2.groupby(pd.cut(df2['date'], bins=df1['date'], labels=df1['date'][:-1])) \
       ['Val'].sum().reset_index()

        date  Val
0 2020-02-01  153
1 2020-02-02   32
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code with explanations. I know there are some quicker and easier ways, but this one is easy to understand. Just replace the dummy data with yours.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ ==  "__main__" :
    # create pandas dataframe with custom series input with column names date and Val
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': 
                        pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', end='31/12/2000',periods=8, normalize=True), 
                        'Val': np.zeros(8)})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': 
                        pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', end='31/12/2000', periods=8, normalize=True), 
                        'Val': np.random.randint(0, 100, 8)})

    # I want the df1.val[i] to be the sum of all the values in df2 between the dates df1.date[i] and df1.date[i+1] .
    # I want the output to be in a new dataframe with column names date and sumVal.
    # The output dataframe should only have the rows for which there is a match between the dates in df1[i] and df1[i+1].
    # The output dataframe should be sorted by date.
    # The output dataframe should have the same number of rows as df1.
    # The output dataframe should have the same number of columns as df1.
    # The output dataframe should have the same index as df1.
    print('-' * 50)
    print('df1')
    print(df1)
    print('-' * 50)
    print('df2')
    print(df2)

    for i in range(0, len(df1) - 1):
        # add sum of all the values in df2 bfore the end date of df1 (i.e. i + 1)
        df1.loc[i, 'Val'] += df2.loc[df2['date']
                                    <= df1['date'][i+1], 'Val'].sum()
        # remove all sums from below date threshold (i.e. values under i)
        df1.loc[i, 'Val'] += df2.loc[df2['date']
                                     < df1['date'][i], 'Val'].sum()
        

    print('-' * 50)
    print('df1')
    print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I need a vectorised version tbh

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend duckdb for such tasks:

```
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['date'] = ['2020-02-01', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-03']
df1['Val'] = [0,0,0]
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1.loc[0:len(df1)-2, 'date_2'] = df1.loc[1:len(df1)-1, 'date'].values


df2['date'] = ['2020-02-01-10:00:00', '2020-02-01-13:54:09', '2020-02-02-11:33:17 ']
df2['Val'] = [98,55,32]
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

test_df = duckdb.query(
    """select t.date, sum(t.Val) as Val
    from (
       select t1.date, t2.Val, t2.date as date_validation 
       from df1 as t1 
       left join df2 as t2 on t1.date < t2.date and t1.date_2 >= t2.date
       ) t 
       group by t.date
       order by t.date"""
).to_df()
```